# Given a noun, what's the best way to determine the "gender"?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I'm given the task of determining whether an advertisement is suited for male or female.
What's the best way of determining this?

The words looks like this:

```
Cheetos
Coca Cola
Nike
Ferrari
24
Arrested Development
Transformers
Nestle
American Eagle
```

For each word, I'd like to know if it's more associated to male or female. It doesn't have to be correct.  I know it's hard to tell if "nike" is suited towards male or female. Just any methodology would help me brainstorm.

Comment: Sentences do not have gender.  Nouns, pronouns, and adjectives do.  English (historically) had three genders of nouns: masculine, feminine, neuter, but other languages have more than three genders. What is the natural language?

Comment: @Tim Lets consider English, what I want is `hero:masculine/feminie, king:masculine queen:feminine`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Testing for these kinds of associations is very difficult, and I doubt you could do it without doing actual research. However, if you're up for it, you should look into the "Implicit Association Test." You can find a demonstration of it here:

http://www.understandingprejudice.org/iat/index2.htm

Here's a Wikipedia page with more information.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_Association_Test

It's controversial, but there's at least some evidence that it is a reliable tool for measuring unconscious bias.

I would have some ethical qualms about using this kind of research for writing advertisements. But I'm inclined to take your question seriously; I'll leave you to consider the ethical implications on your own.

Comment: is there an api or an online ai service to do this :)